# Is there a good way to do version control when developing pylons applications with dependencies?

Tags: python, controls, version

I'm developing two pylons applications at the same time. Application B uses a lot of the controllers, etc. in application A. Both applications are under active development, but for administrative reasons, they have to be kept separate.

Is there a convenient way to do version control so that changes to A are easy to pull into B?  It'd be great if there were a way to do this with svn, since it already plays nice with pylons and paster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable way to do what you want is to have application B work against formal releases of application A, even if those releases are labled *beta* or *release candidate*. IOW, do not treat application A as source code, but as an imported module installed with `setup.py` or other means.

Doing it this way will let you move application B from one well known stage of A to the other, plus you'll be able to report bugs or incompatibilities against specific releases, and go back to previous releases when a new A breaks B.

Comment: So in that case, the bulk of the pylons files and directories in A will have to be separated from the module(s) I want to inherit in B.  It's almost as if I have pylons applications A and B that both use a separate python module C.  Is that right?  thanks!

Comment: @Abe. You're right, except that the physical separation is not what matters. What matters is to treat the code that belongs to other sub-projects as if it was from a third-party. That is the B project must know which version of A it is using, and must not make any changes to A code. How to enforce that is up to you. It is OK to include the A code in B's repository (as it's sometimes done with libraries) as long as it continues to be treated as third-party.